# list generator in python2 and python3

Tags: python-3.x

```py
from random import randint

functions = []

for n in range(8):

    def f():
        return f.t

    f.t = randint(1, 8)

    functions.append(f)

# 1
result = []
for f in functions:
    result.append(f())
print(result)

# 2
result = []
for f in functions:
    result.append(f.t)
print(result)

# 3
result = [f.t for f in functions]
print(result)

# 4
result = [f() for f in functions]
print(result)
```

question:
if I run the code with python2, code section 1-4 output are the same, but with python3, section 4 is different with others, its value is a list with 8 same values which are the last one of the above list。

why

example:
python2

```
[1, 6, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 1]
[1, 6, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 1]
[1, 6, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 1]
[1, 6, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 1]
```

python3

```
[6, 5, 8, 7, 5, 1, 8, 4]
[6, 5, 8, 7, 5, 1, 8, 4]
[6, 5, 8, 7, 5, 1, 8, 4]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a scoping issue.

In cases #1 and #2, there is only one `f` at a time, always replaced in global scope by the loop variable, so any reference to `f` ends up referring to the `f` assigned to in the loop.

In case #3, it's a little trickier; on Python 2, it's like case #1 and #2, and on Python 3, it's always a local variable with an attached attribute, and no use of the global `f`, but since you never call it, just access the attached attribute directly, you get what you expect.

But in case #4, on Python 3, there are two meaningful `f`s involved during the listcomp, the one locally scoped to the listcomp (which changes each loop), and the one in global scope (the one left over from the last time you set `f` outside the listcomp). When you call `f()` inside the listcomp, it's the local `f`, but it's looking for the global scope `f` (of which there is just one) to find the value of `f.t` (it has no way of knowing there is a local that just happens to share the same name). So even though you have eight different functions, they're all checking the `.t` attribute associated with a single global `f` function and seeing that `f` function's `.t` attribute (note how the repeated value is the same value seen *last* for all the other attempts; that's what's left over in global scope at the end of those loops).

The reason this doesn't occur on Python 2 is because listcomps on Python 2 don't have separate scope, they operate in the same scope they're invoked it, so they replace the global `f` on each loop just like the other loops do. If you want Python 2 to behave the same way as Python 3, make it a generator expression (genexpr) wrapped in the `list` constructor instead, e.g.:

```
# 5
result = list(f() for f in functions)
print(result)
```

Genexprs always have their own scope (they were introduced later than listcomps, and had their own scope from the beginning, they didn't need to wait for Python 3 to introduce a compatibility breaking change).

The correct fix for this (that will remove this inadvertent global dependency that is actually making your code behave incorrectly, according to any sane reading; right now, `functions[3]()` will report the `f.t` associated with the last assigned `f`, not the expected `functions[3].t`), is to make your functions closures that each store their own separate value in closure scope, not global scope. For example:

```
from random import randint

functions = []

def make_f():
    def f():
        return t
    f.t = t = randint(1, 8)  # Only needs f.t because you try to access it elsewhere
    return f

for n in range(8):
    functions.append(make_f())  # No need to even assign to a global f

# 1
result = []
for f in functions:
    result.append(f())
print(result)

# 2
result = []
for f in functions:
    result.append(f.t)
print(result)

# 3
result = [f.t for f in functions]
print(result)

# 4
result = [f() for f in functions]
print(result)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZDRasMwDEXf/RUX@uLACHTdQynsG/YBpQwvkVezRDa2zMjXZ3GahkD3MCYwRrLu0ZXDIFfPh3G00feIhtvpcn3wUebMsShlMzfiPCe84nxRqiWL3nzRu9XVSWGKUlmTEpEkR4bMBVvLpCxnQer9E44VsMMbdwOYqE1z1wc1JifC4DMkDhAP0zSUEpyAukTfV4qkNhPsZM9HMBwX@ifp42JjdV2bEIhbfbdcKbXDXkVKuZPbSgVhC2IVnZYhpecOmLUhlgVuDzPp@T@kWn4hHTak8huPrMuj6GUr0tUfROP4Aw)

Comment: thank you, now I know a lot about variable scope。